# AzureDevops "Azure Appservice Deploy" task settings

Tags: azure-devops, azure-appservice, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019

We are using "AppserviceDeploy" task in Azuredevops to deploy the web package to Azure Appservice.

Is ther any way to sett below properties to the appservice settings as part of the azuredevops "AppService Deploy" task to ensure that these properties are disabled after the new package deployment to the appservice slots.

```
FTP state: Disabled
Http version: 2.0
HTTPS Only: On
```

Answer (score 1):

A deployment does not interfere with the *configuration* of your Azure resource. If the resource has these settings now, they will not have changed after a deployment.

To make sure the App Service has the correct settings, have a look at using either [Infrastructure as Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/devops/deliver/what-is-infrastructure-as-code) or tools like the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/).

Integrating (one of) these in a pipeline is fairly straight-forward and it enables you to ensure the App Service has the correct settings after each deployment.

An example for setting the `HTTPS Only` flag using the Azure CLI [az webapp update command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-update) looks something like this:

`az webapp update -g <YOUR-RESOURCE-GROUP> -n <YOUR-APPSERVICE> --https-only true`

To set properties that are not directly addressable, have a look at the `--set` parameter.

There's an Azure CLI task available in Azure Pipelines which, once configured, should look a bit like this:

[image: Azure Pipeline with Azure CLI task]

Comment: We provisioned our appservice using Terraform and where we havent set these properties as part of IAC, because that are optional values. But then we have manually set those properties to correct settings from the portal. But we noticed that after the web application deployments , the properties are sometimes ( not everytime) changing to the wrong settings settings like,FTP state: Enabled, Http version:  , HTTPS Only: OFF etc. And these were complaining Azure advisor.

Comment: So not sure what makes here reverting the settings in the appservice. We are using Azuredeploy task in Azuredevops pipeline, where its just uploading the webapackage.zip from the build to the appservice root folder, first to the staging slot and then swap task to swapping from staging slot to prod slot  In this case, what can be the root cause. ?

Comment: Also would like to know, can we set these properties as part of the "appservice deploy task" itself  or we need to have azrecli task seperately to ensure these paramaters as u mentioned after each deployments?